# 450 Error with Postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server

I have setup postfix to send outgoing mail, It works fine for most of the cases except for some e.g duke.alumni.edu where it gives me a 450 error, even though the email address is valid.

This is the exact error I get
Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command))

Any suggestions on how I can rectify this?

Comment: What's the sender address (or more precisely the domain part of the sender address) your MTA is offering to `duke.alumni.edu`?

Comment: it is customerservice@carsala.com

Comment: Domain might be wrong according to this URL: http://www.dukealumni.com/get-involved/support-daa/alumni-email-address (shouldn't it be alumni.duke.edu?)

Answer (score 1):

Just to check, neither a dig to alumni.edu nor to duke.alumni.edu gives any answer.
An whois to alumni.edu also returns no match.

You are sure that the subdomain duke.alumni.edu is valid in your environment?